# Use the DBSCAN algorithm on data

Tags: python, outliers, dbscan

I'm trying to apply the `DBSCAN` algorithm on a small dataframe to make outlier prediction after. All the columns have numeric values but I keep getting the same error even though I have no null values.

This is my code to call the algorithm:

```
    db = DBSCAN(eps=0.09, min_samples=10).fit(dfc)
    m = loop.LocalOutlierProbability(dfc).fit()
    scores_noclust = m.local_outlier_probabilities
    m_clust = loop.LocalOutlierProbability(dfc, 
    cluster_labels=list(db.labels_)).fit()
    scores_clust = m_clust.local_outlier_probabilities
    print(list(scores_clust))
```

I get this error:

> ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could
>   not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting
>   rule ''safe''

I don´t understand why, since I have no null values.

Comment: `nan`, not `null`. You obviously are not passing numbers to somewhere.

Comment: Yes, i had a column that was still a object but somehow when i made 
         pd.to_numeric(dfc['Idade']).astype(int)     nothing happened, it didn't give error but the column stayed as object

Comment: Did you save the result? dfc['Idade'] = pd.to_numeric(dfc['Idade']).astype(int) ?

Comment: dfc['Idade'].astype(int)
dfc.dtypes

Comment: That's not enough. astype only returns a new serie, it doesn't modify the current serie.

Comment: Nome          int64
Idade        object
Atividade     int64
Dia           int64
dtype: object                After that i try to see the type of each column and 'Idade' stays an object

Comment: Oh thank you, the to_numeric doesn´t modify either?

Comment: Indeed, you always have to assign back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, it seems that you have a column that has objects that you need to cast into integers.

```
dfc['Idade'] = pd.to_numeric(dfc['Idade']).astype(int)
```

Just doing the cast is not enough, it just returns a new serie, but it won't modify the old one in place, you have to do this explicitly.